# Requests Dialog code does nothing

Tags: facebook, dialog, request

This code does nothing. I replaced the YOUR_APP_ID with my app ID entered this code into a new file and it produces no output what so ever. I'm missing something?

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
  </script>
  <script>
     FB.init({ 
        appId:'YOUR_APP_ID', cookie:true, 
        status:true, xfbml:true 
     });

     FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', 
        message: 'Here is a new Requests dialog...'});
  </script>
```

I got from here:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/453

UPDATE: 
Code is working great for canvas but for page tab just load suggest to friends dialog box and exits without sending the invitation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things that might be happening:

1) **The pop-up is being blocked**

To fix this, you need to have the request triggered on a user action. Otherwise most browsers block automatic popups on page load. Try this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="apprequest()">Do request</a>
<script>
     FB.init({appId:'YOUR_APP_ID', cookie:true,status:true, xfbml:true});
     function apprequest () {
         FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests',
            message: 'Here is a new Requests dialog...'});
     }
</script>
```

Another trick is to force it to use the 'iframe' display method (instead of a popup) which is not blocked by browsers:

```
FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests','display':'iframe',
    message: 'Here is a new Requests dialog...'});
```

2) **The FB JS library has not loaded yet**

This will really only be a problem if you are using the [asynchronous loading](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) technique, which you are not in this example.  But if you were, and you see the error "FB not defined" in your JavaScript console, then you just need to make sure you either have the request popup trigger on a user event (like the link above), or call it in the asynchronous callback.

Good luck!

Comment: You are my hero!!! Tha's why all sample did not work for me, I'm  using the asynchronous loading. I include this example in the middle of my page. Now I try a new page, a fresh one and works! Many thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help out! Feel free to mark this question as "answered" if your problem was solved. Cheers!