# having an issue with invite friends dialog with facebook

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-php-sdk

i have a button with an if statement, and the idea is that when the button is pressed, the facebook multi friends invite dialog shows up.

I did have it showing up when the main canvas loaded, but i needed it when the button was clicked, and now when i click the button it just refreshes the background.

here is my statement:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['invite']))
{
?>
<div id="fb-root"></div>"
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({ 
        appId:'161051054059696', 
    cookie:true, 
        status:true, 
    xfbml:true 
     });

     FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', 
        message: 'Share a geordie wall post with your mates!'});
  </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

instead of closing and opening the php tags i tried using echo but that wasn't very successful either. Personally i think my if statement looks like it should work, but obviously not.

hopefully someone can help.

my edited code:

```
<div align="center">
<form method="post">
<input type="image" name="invite" src="images/invite.png"   onClick="inviteFriend();">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['invite']))
{
?>
<div id="fb-root"></div>"
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({ 
    appId:'161051054059696', 
cookie:true, 
    status:true, 
xfbml:true 
 });

function inviteFriend(){
     FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', 
        message: 'Share a geordie wall post with your mates!'});
}
</script>

<?php
}
?>
```

i just realized that in my original code, i didn't include my button code. I have my own image to use as a button if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP is server side. So when the user click in a button, the php side, doesnt exist anymore.

You have to create a javascript funcion.

```
function inviteFriend(){
    FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', 
        message: 'Share a geordie wall post with your mates!'});
}
```

And associate the button click to the function.

```
<input type="button" onClick="inviteFriend();" value="Invite" />
```

Comment: i updated my code but to no avail. I changed my button and it done nothing, changed where things where in my code and still nothing. I will edit my post with how my code looks now.

Comment: The problem was because you had put input type="image". The correct is  type="button". This way you dont need a image.

Comment: i did need an image as the default button was horrible, i had my own button to use. figured it out now though. But it still wouldnt work even when i changed it to a button

Comment: Do you know what is the message error ? The Facebook invite dialog apers ?

Comment: there was no error message, it just didnt appear. but i got it to work . i posted the solution as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so i managed to get the result i was looking for. I found it here [Requests Dialog code does nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366150/requests-dialog-code-does-nothing/8368133#8368133)

so i changed my code, removed the form and used this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>"
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="inviteFriend()"><img src="images/invite.png"></a>
<script>
FB.init({ 
    appId:'161051054059696', 
cookie:true, 
    status:true, 
xfbml:true 
 });

function inviteFriend(){
 FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests', 
    message: 'Share a geordie wall post with your mates!'});
}
</script>
```

so there was actually no need to use an if statement, or a submit button. Just a simple image with the onclick